# Preventing a HTML element from oscillating up and down when changing padding

Tags: html, css

I decided to write a basic blackjack card game using HTML, CSS, and JS, and I'm having a problem where a card oscillates up and down because I'm changing the top margin of the card.

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: margin-top, border;
}

.card:hover {
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 5px solid #3000A0;
  z-index: 0 !important;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: margin-top, border;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">Card</div>
```

So when I hover over the card, the top margin of 50px is removed and the card slides up. However, if I hover over the bottom 50px of the card, the card will slide up (out of the selection of `:hover`, and the card starts to slide back down. The card will then become selected, slide up, become unselected, slide down... repeat.

I tried to fix this by adding

```css
.card::after {
  content: "";
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

but it didn't seem to do anything.

I considered a solution by adding `<div>`s before and after the card element and changing their heights, but I'd rather use a CSS solution before JS for this scenario. What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include any applicable HTML or JS so we have a minimal reproducible example to work from.

Comment: Are you talking about margin or padding? There's not any padding in the CSS you provided.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to give us the whole picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :after to make an extension of the :hover area on the card. Make the card relative and then absolute position the :after below the card. You can set a background-color on the :after to see where your psudo hover state covers.

```css
.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: margin-top, border;
    position: relative;
}

.card:hover:after {
    content: '';
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -5px;
    right: -5px;
}

.card:hover {
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 5px solid #3000A0;
    z-index: 0 !important;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: margin-top, border;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
```

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet demo. This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I didn't have the original :hover selector in the code. It should be better now.

Comment: This answer solved the problem, where the other answer seemed to just create a box in the top left corner of the card. I was actually looking earlier for a solution that used `::after`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When animating elements based on mouse position it's best to delegate the location of the event to another element (in this case, a parent) and animate the `transform` property as it is only a visual transform (padding, margin, etc. affect the document flow).

For example:

```css
.card-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.card-wrapper:hover .card {
  z-index: 0 !important;
  border: 5px solid #3000A0;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-wrapper">
  <div class="card">Card</div>
</div>
```

I added a border and padding to the parent to show you the bounds of the parent. As the mouse enters/exits the parent the child card animates without affecting other elements.

Note that the bounds of the parent *includes the child* as it transforms to extend beyond the top of the parent.